# Filter/shorten the AJAX/get html by ID

Tags: jquery, html-parsing, urlfetch

I am currently rewriting my error/faq messages using markdown(instead of previously used HTML content stored inside database). Now, I have temporarily setup a page `errors.php` where a text-area shows the content I have to edit with two small input boxes for error code and number.

Currently, when I click on the fetch button(see image 1), it fetches the HTML as is and puts it inside the textarea(see image 2).

I instead want something similar to `$.load(<link> + " #content")` with AJAX. Is this possible?

### jQuery

```
$('#Fetch').on( 'click', function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var MyUrl = 'http://******/faq.php?code=' + $('input[name=code]').val() + "&num=" + $('input[name=number]').val();
    $.ajax( {
        url: MyUrl,
        type: "get",
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function( data ) {
            $('#MyArea').val(data);
        }
    });
});
```

---

The above works perfect with just one flaw. It dumps the entire page's HTML content inside the text-area. I want to only have (suppose) the data from `#content` on `faq.php` page. It is possible by using the infamous [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) for HTML but I wanted a cleaner solution for the same.

---

[image: Image 1]
 <sub>Image 1</sub>

---

[image: Image 2]
 <sub>Image 2</sub>

Comment: I can not understand what is it you actually want. To replace the textarea? add it under it...i please be more specific.

Comment: @georgi-it I want to set the value of textarea as HTML inside a div with id `#content` from `faq.php` page. I'll edit my question too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so i got an idea which is not the cleanest but is going to work i guess.

So this is your code :

```
$('#Fetch').on( 'click', function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var MyUrl = 'http://******/faq.php?code=' + $('input[name=code]').val() + "&num=" + $('input[name=number]').val();
    $.ajax( {
        url: MyUrl,
        type: "get",
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function( data ) {
            $('#MyArea').val(data);
        }
    });
});
```

We can change the success and to the following: Create a `<div></div>` container with `display:none` style, then populate this div and after that get the #content from it. So it would look something like this:

```
$('#Fetch').on( 'click', function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var MyUrl = 'http://******/faq.php?code=' + $('input[name=code]').val() + "&num=" + $('input[name=number]').val();
    $.ajax( {
        url: MyUrl,
        type: "get",
        dataType: 'html',
        success:  function (data) {
               $("body").append("<div id='contentContainer'></div>").css("display","none");
               $("#contentContainer").html(data);
               var content = $("#contentContainer #content").html();
               $("#MyArea").val(content);
                   }
    });
```

After that you can delete the div but you got the point.

EDIT:

Okay here's the better idea:
You need to actually parse that info to jQuery variable and from there you can parse html like from DOM.

```
$('#Fetch').on( 'click', function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var MyUrl = 'http://******/faq.php?code=' + $('input[name=code]').val() + "&num=" + $('input[name=number]').val();
    $.ajax( {
        url: MyUrl,
        type: "get",
        dataType: 'html',
        success:  function (data) {
               var container = $(data);
               var content = $(container).find("#content").html();
               $("#MyArea").val(content);
                   }
    });
```

I think this is not gonna get any cleaner. Also it will work fast as we interact with DOM only once.

Comment: You might want to check `$("body").append("<div id='contentContainer'></div>").css("display","none");` as it hides the body `:P`. Also, it fails when I try to pass another code+number value(without submitting the form in first try).

Comment: Well i didn't test the code, you can always then select the contentcontainer and hide it. And the submiting thing.. i don't know what it's exacly but i am sure the solution is simple. GL

Comment: Cool. The second one is neater. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use $( any html ) to make a dom out of it, and then search for "content" container inside it.

for example we can change your function to :-

```
$('#Fetch').on( 'click', function( e ) {
e.preventDefault();
var MyUrl = 'http://******/faq.php?code=' + $('input[name=code]').val() + "&num=" + $('input[name=number]').val();
$.ajax( {
    url: MyUrl,
    type: "get",
    dataType: 'html',
    success:  function (data) {
     var content = $("#content",$(data)).html();
     $("#MyArea").val(content);
        }
});
```